# [rosrun] Couldn't find executable named the listener (C++ program)

Tags: ros, ubuntu, libraries, nodes

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am basically trying to run a listener that listens to the video feed of an *AR.Drone* through the topics being published by the `ardrone_autonomy` node on a *ROS Kinetic* running on a *Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS* on a *Raspberry Pi 3*. Now I have gone through this guide here, and tried to execute the command:

```
rosrun zlab_drone videoFeed_listener
```

But I get the error:

```
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named videoFeed_Listener below /home/sharand/catkin_ws/src/zlab_drone
```

Here's my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(zlab_drone)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  cv_bridge
  ardrone_autonomy
  image_transport
  sensor_msgs
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
)

catkin_package(

)

include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(listener src/videoFeed_Listener.cpp)
target_link_libraries(listener ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252888/%5Brosrun%5D-couldn%27t-find-executable-named-the-listener-(c++-program)/) by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2017-01-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem here is that I name the executable `listener` and try to call on `videoFeed_Listener`. The wiki should be a bit more clear about the `addexecutable()` and `target_link_libraries()` functions. The right call would be:

```
rosrun zlab_drone listener
```

---

Originally posted by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) with karma: 83 on 2017-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0